# Two identical looking MySQL columns apparently contain different characters

Tags: php, mysql

Bit of a strange one, I have a table where I am comparing two strings: `desc_new` and `desc_old`.

`desc_old` is my old data from another database and `desc_new` is newly pulled data from an online source via PHP.

When inserting from php I did the following:

```
$description = trim(strip_tags($description));
```

The data itself looks identical:
[image]

However, when I run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `update_desc` WHERE desc_new != desc_old
```

It returns this row. I'm suspecting there are some hidden characters but I can't for the life of me find out what it is.

I've done a mysql `trim` on both columns to no avail.

If I do a `STRCMP` on them both it returns `1` which means `desc_old` is smaller than `desc_new`

```
SELECT STRCMP(desc_new, desc_old) from update_desc;
```

I've struggled to replicate this in a fiddle but here is a [.sql link to the DB](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15Tmq_IwOqJurN_VRi37mtd9Z3dw70mmp/view?usp=sharing) should anyone want to test.

Comment: Not sure its relevant, but what version of MySQL?

Comment: Using MySQL Version 5.7.30

Comment: And do both columns have the same collation/encoding? like `utf8mb4` or does one have `utf8` and the other `utf8mb4`?

Comment: One has `\"Archfiend\" card.)\nIf` and the other `\"Archfiend\" card.)\r\nIf` Different

Comment: Ah well that explains it. Can I ask how you check that so I know myself going forward?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Just curious, how were you able to spot that?

Comment: Editor. Placed one column above the other. Instantly saw one line was longer than the other. Not always that easy. Editor also allows me to switch between text and Hex, that helps with the invisible char spotting

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly. Based on that, running $description = str_replace("\r\n","\n", $description); on the php side has fixed the issue for me.